# how you make the index for search filters on categories?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table product_categories like this:

```
CREATE TABLE product_categories (
  id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  p_id UUID REFERENCES product(id),
  category VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  sub_category VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT I_U_P_C_SC UNIQUE (p_id, category, sub_category)
)
```

I used constraint unique that no category is double with product_id.

Then I always get the categories so I make some times queries where I only need the p_id

then I create a new index:

```
CREATE INDEX I_SC_PID ON product_categories(p_id)
```

But I also want to search categories like this:

```
WHERE categorie = 'clothes' and sub_categorie = '..'
```

or only categorie:

```
WHERE categorie = 'Clothes'
```

So what I have to do now to opimize my query ? I mean I have so set index then I have to create 2 new indexes for the two examples above ?

Then I dont have too many indexes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, no - you didn't do it right. Table isn't normalized and data model requires some additional tables ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NlK8TkYh)):

```
create table category
  (category_id int primary key,
   name        varchar
  );
create table sub_category
  (sub_category_id int primary key,
   name            varchar
  );
create table product
  (product_id      int primary key,
   name            varchar
  );
create table product_categories
  (id              int generated always as identity primary key,
   product_id      int references product,
   category_id     int references category,
   sub_category_id int references sub_category,
   --
   constraint iupcsc unique (product_id, category_id, sub_category_id)
  );
create index i1_prodcat_prod on product_categories (product_id);
create index i2_prodcat_cat  on product_categories (category_id);
create index i3_prodcat_sub  on product_categories (sub_category_id);
```

Query would then join as many tables as necessary (I joined all of them), along with filter you need:

```
select p.name as product_name,
       c.name as category_name,
       s.name as subcat_name
from product_categories pc 
  join product p on p.product_id = pc.product_id
  join category c on c.category_id = pc.category_id
  join sub_category s on s.sub_category_id = pc.sub_category_id
where c.name = 'clothes'
  and s.name = 'shirts';
```

Comment: thank you very much, but why you write " int references category " and not " int references category(id) " ?

Comment: You're welcome. Database is smart enough that it knows *which* column makes a primary or unique key that can be referenced by a foreign key constraint. Yes - you can specify it yourself, but you don't have to.